# isomorphic adjacency matrices to one matrix

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism, adjacency-matrix

I need to generate lots of graphs to train my code. But it didn't have any impact if training graphs are isomorphic. So I need to eliminate isomorphic graphs to save time.

For this reason, now I'm using a simple BFS from one of the nodes with the biggest degree as the start point. It already improves a lot but I know it could be better.

How could I improve this or are there any better solutions out there?